# How to update records using get method through admin panel

Tags: php, mysqli

Good Evening! I'm trying to update a record in database through my Admin panel but don't know how to do it or may be my logic is not right. Here is my code.

Update query not working .

```
    <?php 
        include 'include/dbConnection.php';
    ?>

    <?php

        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $title = $_GET['Book_Title'];
        $edition = $_GET['Book_Edition'];
        $author = $_GET['Author_Name'];
        $pubication = $_GET['Book_Publication'];
        $copies = $_GET['Book_No_Of_Copies'];
        $price = $_GET['Book_Price'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM book";
        $run = mysqli_query($query);

        foreach ($run as $key) { ?>



    <form method="GET" action="updateBook.php">
        <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $key['Book_Title']; ?>" />
        <input typt="text" name="edition" value="<?php echo $key['Book_Edition']; ?>" />
        <input typt="text" name="author" value="<?php echo $key['Author_Name']; ?>" />
        <input typt="text" name="pubication" value="<?php echo $key['Book_Publication']; ?>" />
        <input typt="text" name="copies" value="<?php echo $key['Book_No_Of_Copies']; ?>" />
        <input typt="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $key['Book_Price']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />

    </form>

<?php } 

        $sql = "UPDATE book SET Book_Title='$title',Book_Edition='$edition',Author_Name='$author',
        Book_Publication='$pubication',Book_No_Of_Copies='$copies',Book_Price='$price'
        WHERE Book_ID='$id'";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

            header("location: viewBook.php");

        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);

}

?>

        <?php 
        } 
        $sql = "UPDATE book SET Book_Title='$title',Book_Edition='$edition',Author_Name='$author', Book_Publication='$pubication',Book_No_Of_Copies='$copies',Book_Price='$price' WHERE Book_ID='$id'";
     if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) { 
    header("location: viewBook.php");
     } 
    else { 
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn); 
    } 
    mysqli_close($conn); 
    } 
    ?>
```

I have added your php code in question. Please do some correction if needed. and describe your code and your problems in details.

Comment: you are missing an SQL UPDATE command... you are only using a SELECT command. Thus, you will not update anything.

Comment: @KevSto there it is right under the form element
<?php } 

  $sql = "UPDATE book SET Book_Title='$title',Book_Edition='$edition',Author_Name='$author',
  Book_Publication='$pubication',Book_No_Of_Copies='$copies',Book_Price='$price'
  WHERE Book_ID='$id'";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   
   header("location: viewBook.php");
  
  } else {
   echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);

}

?>

Comment: Hi Alisha, I have added your php code in question. Please do some correction if needed. and describe your code and your problems in details.

Comment: At least according to the HTTP specs, a GET should not inflict changes to data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM book where id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$key = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```

**populate data on your view**

```
<form method="GET" action="updateBook.php">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $key['Book_Title']; ?>" />
    <input typt="text" name="edition" value="<?php echo $key['Book_Edition']; ?>" />
    <input typt="text" name="author" value="<?php echo $key['Author_Name']; ?>" />
    <input typt="text" name="pubication" value="<?php echo $key['Book_Publication']; ?>" />
    <input typt="text" name="copies" value="<?php echo $key['Book_No_Of_Copies']; ?>" />
    <input typt="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $key['Book_Price']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```